# Pass file contents to a function instead of downloading the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, download, nightmare

I am using [`Nightmare`](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) in order to automatically download a user-specific generated `csv` file from a web service as follows (rough workflow):

1. `.goto()` website
2. `.insert()` credentials and `.click()` login button
3. `.wait()` for desired DOM element to be loaded
4. scrape the landing page to extract some request-specific identifier which is needed to generate the download link for the file I am interested in
5. call `.goto()` on an `export.php` endpoint with some other arguments to download the `csv` file. Since Nightmare's Electron Window is displayed, I am asked for a path to store the file to.

Currently, the general overall workflow looks like this:

1. download (and save) the file using Nightmare
2. read file using [`readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) into a string
3. analyze data using [`data-forge-js`](https://github.com/data-forge/data-forge-js#working-with-csv-data), [`pandasjs`](https://github.com/StratoDem/pandas-js) or [`d3-dsv`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv)

By passing the file's contents directly to the data analysis I want to get rid of saving the file in step 1 and reading that local file in step 2. I do not want to store the original `csv` file locally. Since I do not want to enable Nightmares Electron Window later in production I am looking for an approach to pass the file's contents to the data handling function directly and get rid of those unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window.URL object methods to store your data. The following retrieves a binary blob but you could use content-types and response-types to return strings.

```
        xmlhttp.open('GET', PHOTO_URL, true);
        xmlhttp.responseType = 'blob';

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var blob = xmlhttp.response;
                    photoImg.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    setTimeout(setOnCampusImage,0);     
                } else {
                    photoImg.src = 'unknown.png';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your code a bit further? This seems like a snippet out of some project. With the information provided in your answer I was not able to adapt it properly to fit my needs.

Comment: Can you post your code? I'm not 100% sure of what you're attempting.